# Ruby BigDecimal method error

Tags: ruby

I created `log_slow` alias, and it is not working:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/math'
require 'bigdecimal/util'

module BigMath
  alias :log :log_slow
  def log(x, prec)
    if x <= 0 || prec <= 0
      raise ArgumentError, "Zero or negative argument for log"
    end
    return x if x.infinite? || x.nan?
    sign, fraction, power, exponent = x.split
    fraction = BigDecimal(".#{fraction}")
    power = power.to_s.to_d
    log_slow(fraction, prec) + (log_slow(power, prec) * exponent)
  end
end

include BigMath
number = BigDecimal("1234.5678")
Math.log(number)
prec = 50
puts BigMath.log_slow(number, prec).round(prec).to_s("F")
puts BigMath.log(number, prec).round(prec).to_s("F")
puts BigMath.log(number ** 1000, prec).round(prec).to_s("F")
```

I get an error:

```
in `<module:BigMath>': undefined method `log_slow' for module `BigMath' (NameError)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `alias` expects the new name first, no? And isn't alias a keyword taking actual method names, not symbols?

Comment: You're looking for [`alias_method`](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.3/module#method-i-alias_method). See the argument ordering there.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm: `alias` works too.

Comment: @DaveNewton `alias` takes either method names or symbols since some version.

Comment: @sawa Ah; good to know--thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your alias should be something like this to escape the error

```
module BigMath

    def log(x, prec)
      #your code
    end


   alias log_slow log
end
```

Format:

```
alias new_name old_name
```

Comment: Either `alias new_name old_name` or `alias :new_name :old_name`